# Undefined reference error on QQuickWindow from cmake

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, qml, undefined-reference, catkin

I am in the middle of integrating catkin project with qt-quick project.
I made a rugged CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (qml_ros_camera)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COVERAGE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")

# set up a mapping so that the Release configuration for the Qt imported target is
# used in the COVERAGE CMake configuration.
set_target_properties(Qt5::Core PROPERTIES MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_COVERAGE "RELEASE")

get_target_property(QtCore_location Qt5::Core LOCATION)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Quick Core Network)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Declarative)

catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(HEADER_FILES ~/image_transport_ws/src/qml_ros_camera/src/videoplayer.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES ~/image_transport_ws/src/qml_ros_camera/src/main.cpp
    ~/image_transport_ws/src/qml_ros_camera/src/videoplayer.cpp
    )

set(qml_ros_camera_RESOURCES qml.qrc)
qt5_add_resources(qml_ros_camera_RESOURCES_RCC ${qml_ros_camera_RESOURCES})

add_executable(qml_ros_camera
    ${SOURCE_FILES}
    ${qml_ros_camera_RESOURCES_RCC})

target_link_libraries(qml_ros_camera ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Core}
    ${Qt5Declarative_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

include_directories(
    ~/image_transport_ws/src/qml_ros_camera/src/
    /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQuick
    /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore
    ${Qt5Declarative_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
qt5_use_modules(qml_ros_camera Widgets Qml)
```

The compile error I have:

```
CMakeFiles/qml_ros_camera.dir/src/main.cpp.o: 
In function `QQuickWindow* qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(QObject*)': main.cpp:
(.text._Z12qobject_castIP12QQuickWindowET_P7QObject
[_Z12qobject_castIP12QQuickWindowET_P7QObject]+0x16)
: undefined reference to `QQuickWindow::staticMetaObject'
```

I'm using Qt-creator and C++. The problem is associated with my poor understanding on how CMakeLists.txt works. How may I fix this terrible compile error?

Answer (score 0):

Try linking like that:

```
target_link_libraries(...
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Quick
    ...
```

And you don't need include_directories/add_definitions for qt stuff.